# Can't find the error: VLOOKUP not returning the value

Tags: excel, formatting, syntax-error, excel-formula, vlookup

I am working with an excel file and I am trying to "map" some values with the vLookUp function.

The first parameter of the vLookUp function is giving me headaches: The function works with certains values (typed by hand in a text format)...but doesnt work with pre-generated values (the sames ones...but generated from an ERP system..). I checked to make sure that I was looking for "same nature" values ( text vs text ) ...but I can't find out why the first 3 values (typed by hand) are fine... but the last 3 (pre generated) gives me a #N/A error: It has to be a difference of "format" ..but I can't find out where's  the difference...

This is the formula used: =VLOOKUP(D1;$A$1:$B$219;2;FALSE)

[The actual file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89hm1g3a1l6em0z/vlookup.xlsx)

```
1008600 379.99      1008600 379.99
1008601 379.99      1008601 379.99
1010600 449.99      1010600 449.99
1010601 449.99      1010601 #N/A
1013600 489.99      1013600 #N/A
1014601 509.99      1014601 #N/A
1015600 569.99          
1018603 679.99          
1019600 809.99
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using this formula will address the issue highlighted by RocketDonkey

`=VLOOKUP(TEXT(D1,"#"),$A$1:$B$219,2,FALSE)`

Comment: This worked...but I still don't underdstand why. Changing the format of a cell via ctrl+1 -->text isn't the same as TEXT(value,"#")  ?

Comment: Changing the format doesn't actually change the underlying data. You need to force a recalculation after your format change for the data to change (for example using a text to columns).

Comment: You can also concatenate with "" to convert to text in the formula, like this `=VLOOKUP(D1&"",$A$1:$B$219,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you haven't converted you values in column `A` to numbers. Since the first three values in your lookup range are themselves strings, they are matching the stringified numbers.

In order to fix, click on one of the numbers in column `A`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to select the entire column, and then click on the exclamation mark and select `Convert to number`:

[image]

After that, you'll notice that your previous values now show errors, so follow the same process to conver them to numbers as well. @nutsch's solution is does not require you to modify your data, so if the type of your data is not crucial, that is a good fix as well :)

[image]

Comment: This worked... but I don't get it.  I was comparing "string"values ( CTRL+1 ..format->"text" for all the cell in the document). How come comparing 2 strings values doesnt work ? Transforming values to number would of gave us a  number VS string lookup no?

Comment: @user1023021 I experience this a lot when importing data from other sources - oftentimes even converting the number via `Ctrl+1` isn't enough to coerce it into the proper format. My best guess is it is more to do with the underlying system-level representation of the number. You can alternatively do the Paste-Special-multiply-by-1 trick, but this way is a bit easier.

Comment: my favorite way to force the text to number is the text to columns. Alt A E, Alt+F, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a major pain for me as well(Excel is full of stupid assumptions). What I do is copy the entire column to a text editor, change the column to match the lookup column, and copy and paste the data back into the column. This has worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

May I highlight the little noticeable reply that Barry Houdini came with in 2012 above:

```
    =VLOOKUP(D1&"",$A$1:$B$219,2,FALSE)
```

that really works (for me in Excel 2010), despite you are dealing with Numbers or a mix of Numbers or Text strings.

Cudos to Barry, you are a truely Houdini